# Animated auto scroll effect to div onclick

Tags: html

I want animated auto scroll to a particular div

My HTML code

navigation menu

```
<div class="row">
<ul class="icons">
<li><a href="dubai.php"><h4>Events</h4></a></li>
<li><a href="dubai.php"><h4>Cinemas</h4></a></li>
<li><a href="dubai.php"><h4>Shopping</h4></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Div i want to auto scroll

```
<div class="event-list">                               
<h3>Heading</h3>
<p>Details</p>
<a href="detail.php> Read more..</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use a little bit of java script you can you this plugin 
http://jedfoster.com/Readmore.js/ .
it's not a auto scroll but I think it can do the trick

Answer (score 0):

U can move the animate scroll to a particular function using the following code

```
$('html, body').animate( { scrollTop: element.offset().top }, {duration: 400 } );
```

Comment: This code works when page refresh. How to auto scroll when clicking on a button or div?

Comment: You have the call that function when the button or div is clicked.   `$(document).on('click','a', function(){  $('html, body').animate( { scrollTop: element.offset().top }, {duration: 400 } );   })`